# Adding a Shadow for Navigaton Drawer gives an error

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm going to add a shadow to my Navigation Drawer. Here is the code I used.

Created a `navbar_shadow.xml` and added it to drawable. Here is the code.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#111"
    android:endColor="#00000000">
</gradient>
<size
    android:height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:width="5dp">
</size>
```

Then added following code to `NavigationDrawer.java`

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

So, when I'm running this code. It started crash and following error shows. Here is the Logcat I have got.

```
11-27 09:43:47.787    6541-6541/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myayubo, PID: 6541
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.Extract}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myayubo.Extract.onCreate(Extract.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to add my shadow successfully. Thanks.

Comment: mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, GravityCompat.START);  this is line no 63?

Comment: Yes. It is line number 63.

Comment: show your code in activity class extract

Comment: extract means my NavigationDrawer.java. When I added         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, GravityCompat.START); it gives this error. but, without this piece of code Navigation drawer is working.

Comment: you need the whole code of this class?

Comment: there must one problem that it is not getting the refference to R.drawable.navbar_shadow

Comment: Added the code. please look. :)

Comment: you are setting  `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, GravityCompat.START);`before `mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` do this after that... see my answer do like that

Comment: Oh! What a silly mistake. Thanks. My problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should initializ the mDrawerLayout using findViewById

First  findViewById and then add the drawable to the layout

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_extract);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, Gravity.LEFT);/// it should be here after findviewbyid
    mLenear = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.leftDrawer);
```

Comment: Thanks.  This helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have initialized the `mDrawerLayout` using `findViewById`

**EDIT 1:**
Change the order

First initi the layout with findViewById and then add the drawable to the layout

Comment: Yes I did. mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

Comment: is the drawer appearing without the shadow?

Comment: Yes when I remove         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, GravityCompat.START); it is working perfect

Answer (score 0):

Your call to setDrawerShadow needs to be after the findViewById

ie

```
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navbar_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

Currently you are trying to apply the shadow before you have found the view, hence the null pointer.